# In Gtk+, one keyboard event disabled all other ones

Tags: c, gtk

So I want to implement quitting the program by hitting Ctrl+c. I did this:

```
static void
quitit(GtkWidget   *widget,
       GdkEventKey *event,
       gpointer    data)
{
    if(event->state == GDK_CONTROL_MASK &&
       event->keyval == 'c')
        gtk_main_quit();
}

...

int
main(int argc,
     char **argv)
{ 
    ...

    g_signal_connect(window, "key_press_event",
                     G_CALLBACK(quitit), NULL);

    ... (Other keypress events)
}
```

Well, this worked. But the problem is that all other keypress events I connected stopped working, while the mouse clicks still work. I couldn't figure this out. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype of the callback for The `key-press-event` signal is:

```
gboolean  user_function (GtkWidget *widget,
                         GdkEvent  *event,
                         gpointer   user_data): Run Last
```

According to the [GOBject Signal's documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect), it should return TRUE to stop other handlers from being invoked for the event or FALSE to propagate the event further.

Because you are defining `quitit()` as `void`, it can return any value other than FALSE (0).  Therefore, it stops other handlers from being invoked.

The solution is to change the definition for `quitit()` to return a `gboolean` and return FALSE.